Persistent Issue Importing KerasClassifier
I’ve been facing a persistent issue with importing the KerasClassifier library in my Python environment, and I’m hoping to get some advice on how to resolve it.
I keep encountering an intermittent issue where the import sometimes works fine, and at other times, I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_container_adapter' from 'sklearn.utils._set_output' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py)
Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, what did you do to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
From scikeras.wrappers:
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

From tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn:
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

Older Versions of Keras:
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

I’ve tried upgrading the relevant packages (scikit-learn, scikeras, tensorflow) and restarting the environment, but the issue still persists randomly.
Edit : it seems like installing using pip install --no-deps scikeras resolves the issue

This worked for me.
try:
    import scikeras
except ImportError:
    !python -m pip install scikeras



It seems that there are quite a few problems with incompatibilities between scikeras and keras/tensorflow .

I just ran some small tests on google colab : Successfully installed scikeras-0.13.0 scikit-learn-1.5.2 and the problem persists
**
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_container_adapter' from 'sklearn.utils._set_output' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py)
**
